# Can i remove random numbers and letters from a string. But keep only the important ones

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Okey so i know that i can remove letters and numbers from a string by using **preg_replace**. but here is what im trying to do.

Im using a wordpress plugin called **Engage forms**, that stores submitted data in a mySQL database.

The tricky part is that the data that's being submitted is not stored cleanly for some reason.
(reason being that the devs that made the plugin with some purpurs for this and i cant figuer out how they print out without the unknown numbers and letters.)

**Here is what i mean:**
I submit the data

- Firstname: Peter
- Lastname: Stormare
- Email: storm@ren.com
- Phone: 0736997385

---

Here is how the data inside the mySQL database looks and how its being printed out on the webpage:

### Very messy

a:4:{s:18:"firstname25601459863853";s:5:"Peter";s:23:"lastnamn77151459863853";s:8:"Stormare";s:19:"email58511459863853";s:13:"Storm@ren.com";s:21:"phone22101459863853";s:10:"0736997385";}

---

### My attempt at cleaning up the data

So ive tried using my little knowledge and take away as much as i can with:

```
$patterns = array();
        $patterns[0] = '/[{}]/';
        $patterns[1] = '/[a-x]:[0-9]/';
        $patterns[2] = '/[0-9]:/';
        $patterns[3] = '/[a-x]:/';
        $patterns[4] = '/[":"]/';
        $patterns[5] = '/;/';
        $patterns[6] = '/namn[1]/'; 
        $replacements = array();
        $replacements[2] = '';
        $replacements[1] = '';
        $replacements[0] = '';
        $replacements[3] = '';
        $replacements[4] = ' ';
        $replacements[10] = ''

            echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $leadslist);
```

Which should output this now:

firstname25601459863853 Peter lastname77151459863853 Stormare email58511459863853 Storm@ren.com phone22101459863853 0736997385

---

## The Big Question

Is there anyway i can now target the random numbers that follow firstname and the rest, without deleting the phone numbers? (the example phone number is 0736997385.

---

## Possible solution

The best solution atm was submitted by user: Pei-turn.

He showed me how to remove any number bigger then 10 digits. Using this pattern in Preg_replace()

```
$patterns[3] = '/[0-9]{0,9}[0-9]{11,}/';
```

This works very well. Only thing im worried about is if some data might get removed due to weird future form submissions.

Comment: Hey, this is json. use json_decode and json_encode ! Then you have to follow the data when you submit form, to see where numbers are added to your values...

Comment: aha I did not know this was json. I hope i can solve this. Never worked with json code before. thanks for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Random are you sure it's `json`?  it look's like a `serialized` array to me.

Comment: @roullie indeed, this is not JSON. unserialize doesn't work neither...

Comment: Actually, the construction of the serialized data is totally wrong... it says "s18" on a 23 long string... it breaks it all... The correct serialized data should be : `a:4:{s:23:"firstname25601459863853";s:5:"Peter";s:22:"lastnamn77151459863853";s:8:"Stormare";s:19:"email58511459863853";s:13:"Storm@ren.com";s:19:"phone22101459863853";s:10:"0736997385";}`. Here you may use unserialize...

Comment: yes i suspect that its not JSON because in the plugin folder there is one json file that does not look like the cause of this.   However i can see in the php folders were its using the unserialized " $submitted_data = unserialize( $message_result->submitted_data ); "    submitted_data is a what the sql row is named

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A phone number has 10 digits, try to remove all numbersequences shorter than 10 and longer then 10

[0-9]{0,9}
[0-9]{11,}

Comment: Oooops did not see that is was json :D just use json_decode

Comment: Actually, this is not JSON :p

Comment: ah yes that could work. if i just tell it to remove everything shorter then 10 numbers. The random numbers are always 14 digits long! I did think of this myself but i did not know how to tell it so go for number length.   Thanks!

Comment: i put this in:  $patterns[3] = '/[0-9]{0,9} [0-9]{11,}:/';               but its not changing the text :O

Comment: never mind I removed the space in the middle and its printing everything out good now! :D  its a solution that works now. i hope it wont mess up future submittions xD as long as peoples phone numbers dont get crazy it should be fine :D thanks again!